# How to get shade popup on Android Studio OSX version

Tags: macos, android-studio

I am practicing Flutter using Android Studio. Details are as follows

```
Android Studio 3.6.3
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135, built on April 14, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.4
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, io.flutter
```

During the course the author show color shading selection by press `ctrl + q` on his Android Studio windows version like this

[image: shade picker]

I had tried android studio osx mac color shade picker selector, but it does not show related answers to my question

**Questions:**

1. How to use this feature on an OSX?
2. How to call this feature?

Answer (score 0):

For macOS you should try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.